# SSIS Derived Column to add first 3 values of current year (YYY) to a string date (MMDDY)

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis, etl, derived-column

I have a string date value that is missing the 201 of 2019.
The string value `03189101545` which should be `03-18-(201)9 10:15:45`

I did a left from a serial number variable to extract `03189` and can't quite figure out how to add back the full year.

```
LEFT([Serial Number],5)
```

I've tried a cast to date but that fails.

```
(DT_DBTIME)LEFT([Serial Number],5)
```

I though about doing a

```
(DT_DATE) DATEADD("yyyy", 0, (LEFT([Serial Number],5)))
```

but it seems to be the same problem as the cast issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using to following expression, it converts the string into ISO format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` then cast it as date:

```
(DT_DATE)("201" + SUBSTRING([Serial Number], 5,1) + "-" +
    LEFT([Serial Number], 2) + "-" +
    SUBSTRING([Serial Number], 3,2) + " " +
    SUBSTRING([Serial Number], 6,2) + ":" +
    SUBSTRING([Serial Number], 8,2) + ":" +
    RIGHT([Serial Number], 2))
```

If you are looking to only add `201` to the existing value, use:

```
LEFT([Serial Number], 4) + "201 + RIGHT([Serial Number], 7)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I appreciate the two approaches to the issue.